# Twitter Bootstrap repopulate modal with remote page

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to do something like this:
A modal where I load a remote page to show contacts info and also has a button to enable to edit this info and so this button needs to load a new remote page that has a form to edit the contact info.

I'm using the following code to test this behavior and a test is at http://jsfiddle.net/vafleite/jf10pdcj/2/

```js
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if (remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/vafleite/c5dLg852/3/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal" data-target="#myModal">Remote modal button</button>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">...</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following is the first modal that is loaded (which will be the contacts info):

```html
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="modal-edit-buttom"> <span data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/vafleite/62m9h069/1/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true">Edit</span>
            </button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Header test</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Body test</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this one should be loaded from inside the previous modal.
**Note the Edit button in the previous modal**, this is what doesn't work...

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="modal-edit-buttom">
            <span data-load-remote="remote_modal.html" data-target="#myModal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-placebolder-header">Remote modal test</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Remote modal body</h4>
        <hr>
        <p>blah blah blah lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button in the main page the first remote modal loads just fine, the modal already loaded has another button ('Edit' near the modal close button) and this button should load another modal in the same structure, but it't not working.

Someone has any idea about how to do this?!

Comment: why you have 2 `data-target` here `<button type="button" class="modal-edit-buttom"> <span data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/vafleite/62m9h069/1/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true">Edit</span>` when you want to open only 1 modal

Comment: `SyntaxError: unreachable code after return statement`

Comment: You are right. I can remove the `data-remote-target` and change the JS load to this `$($this.data('target')).load(remote);`... But this doesn't affect the load from inside the modal.

Comment: If you look at the firebug console you will note that the js isn't even triggered after the first modal is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the jQuery docs I found that the `on` method doesn't trigger events of dynamically loaded content when used in that way.

To fix it a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events.) must be used.

And so my code became like this

```js
$('#load-wrapper').on('click', '[data-load-remote]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if (remote) {
        $($this.data('target')).load(remote);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="load-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/vafleite/c5dLg852/8/show/" data-target="#myModal">Remote modal button</button>

    <div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">...</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/vafleite/jf10pdcj/3/